# PHP Get Time From X Percentage of Total Time

Tags: php

I don't know if this will make sense but I would like to get the time from percentage of a value, I have the following as an input example:

```
mypercentage = 50; 
mytime = "00:59:59"
```

As you can see, my time is 60 minutes (1 hour) and 50% of that is 30 minutes therefore from the 2 above inputs I would like to get the following output
(50 % of an hour):

```
00:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Explode the string into an array
2. Convert the 3 elements into numbers
3. Find the value in seconds. $array[0]*3600+$array[1]*60+$array[2]
4. Calculate the time from the value in step 3 and the percentage.
5. Use /3600 and /60 to find the hour and minutes and %60 to find the seconds.
6. put the values in an array and implode to a string, or just use

   $hour.":".$minute.":".$second

Comment: I agree with you. From my POV, the best way is to convert the time into seconds, compute those seconds with the percentage and convert it back into the format given in the question

Comment: I second to Florent. Less trouble and more elegant, rather than making lots of conversions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who responded, I found this solution to work:

```
            $mypercentage = 50;
            $mytime = '00:59:59';

            $totaltime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($mytime));

            $seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $totaltime UTC");

            $per_seconds = ($mypercentage / 100) * $seconds;

            $time_from_percentage = gmdate("H:i:s", $per_seconds);
            echo $time_from_percentage;
```